# "EndpointConnectionError : unable to connect to endpoint https://lambda-xyz/wehwk.com

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm new to lambda, I tried invoking a lambda function with another lambda 
using the following script

import boto3
region = 'ca-central-1'

def lambda_handler(event,context):
client.boto3('lambda' , region_name='region')
response = client.invoke(FunctionName='xyz',LogType='None')
print(response)

but im getting "EndpointConnectionError : unable to connect to endpoint https://lambda-xyz/wehwk.com

I also tagged lambda full access policy to this lambda function.

Am I missing something ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `client.boto3('lambda' , region_name='region')` you should use:

```
client = boto3.client('lambda')
```

Observe that you have `client` and `boto3` inverted. Then you can use the client:

```
response = client.invoke(FunctionName='xyz',LogType='None')
print(response)
```